# is django-paypal safe to use it?

Tags: python, django, django-paypal

i'm using `django-paypal` package to implement my site payments

`settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # other apps
    "paypal.standard.ipn",
    "payment",
    "...."
]
....
PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL = "receiverEmail@gmail.com"
PAYPAL_TEST = True
```

`views.py`

```
...
def payment_process(request):
    host = request.get_host()
    paypal_dict = {
        "business": settings.PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL,
        "amount": "99",
        "item_name": "python_book22",
        "invoice": "some invice name22",
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "notify_url": "http://{}{}".format(host, reverse("paypal-ipn")),
        "return_url": "http://{}{}".format(host, reverse("payment:done")),
        "cancel_return": "http://{}{}".format(host, reverse("payment:cancel")),
    }
    form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict)
    return render(request, "payment/payment_process.html", {"form": form})


@csrf_exempt
def Done(request):
    return render(request, "payment/done.html")


@csrf_exempt
def Cancel(request):
    return render(request, "payment/cancel.html")
```

**I have no idea how safe is this**, because in client side it renders a form like this

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" id="id_cmd">
    <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8" id="id_charset">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" id="id_currency_code">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" id="id_no_shipping">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="reciverEmail@gmail.com" id="id_business">                 
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="99" id="id_amount">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="python_book22" id="id_item_name">
    <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="some invice name22" id="id_invoice">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://127.0.0.1:8000/paypal/" id="id_notify_url">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://127.0.0.1:8000/payment/cancel/" id="id_cancel_return">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://127.0.0.1:8000/payment/done/" id="id_return">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" name="submit" alt="Buy it Now">
</form>
```

**Anyone can easily change** `<input type="hidden" name="business" value="reciverEmail@gmail.com" id="id_business">` this and write other email, while system (can't/don't) detect it and the after the payment done to other account it returns the success url (*however the payment was to other account*).

**Any idea ??**
*Sorry if i missed up things or had a misunderstandings*

Comment: This is already addressed in the documentation - use the encrypted button instead of the standard one: https://django-paypal.readthedocs.io/en/stable/standard/encrypted_buttons.html